Quiero Eliminar SQL Server 2022 por completo e instalarlo de nuevo, problemas en la desinstalacion e instalación
Tengo un problema con la desinstalación de SQL Server 2022.
1.- si desinstalo desde el Panel de control en Archivos de programasx86 se elimina pero en Archivos de programas no se elimina a menos que procedas al modo seguro para todos los componentes.
2.- Al instalar nuevamente SQL Server 2022 tengo problemas con la Named Instance(SQLEXPRESS) y InstanceID(SQLEXPRESS) mostrados por la aplicación de instalacióny cuando llego a la etapa de Server Configuration y al final del proceso me muestra error en 4 intentos de instalación
No se como resolver esto, ni con la ayuda de Mónica IA. Este es el mensaje de error:


Action required:
Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the
setup process again.


Feature failure reason:
An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.


Error details:
§ Error installing SQL Server Browser
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
Error code: 0x84BB0001
Visithttps://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=
setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0x88792597%400xBB814387&EvtType=
0x88792597%400xBB814387 to get help on troubleshooting.


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Eso no esta bien desinstalado, pero no entiendo el problema que tenes para desinstarlarlo...

Por favor procede a desinstalar manualmente SQL Server siguiendo los pasos explicados en esta página Web. De manera resumida, la página explica que debe abrir Regedit y realizar los siguientes pasos:
(1) Borre las siguientes claves (keys) en regedit.
--HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server

--HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer

(2) Vaya a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall y elimine todas las subclaves (subkeys) que hacen referencia a SQL Server.
(3) Vaya a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services y elimine todas las claves (keys) que hagan referencia a SQL Server.
(4) Finalmente, cambie el nombre de todas las carpetas relacionadas con SQL Server en el equipo como C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server y subcarpetas.
Luego de estos pasos pruebe instalar de nuevo. Le sugiero descargar SQL Server 2022 nueva vez desde este enlace (SQL Server en el entorno local) y al ejecutar el setup de SQL Server de esta nueva descarga elija instalar la opción gratuita de Express Edition.
